# Is there a way in Google Sheets to join cells in a range using Byrow, Lambda and Join?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the range of cells `A2:W10` with data. Some cells are empty, others not.
In column `X` I would like to join, row by row, the contents of this range excluding the empty cells. The joined results should be delimited by `/`.
Empty rows should be discarded.
I am aware that this can be achieved with one single formula placed on cell `X1` combining `byrow`, `lambda` and `join` functions.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To omit empty rows try this formula

```
=QUERY(BYROW(A2:W10, LAMBDA(tj,(TEXTJOIN("/",1,tj)))),
         "where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: This one works too. I can't upvote yet unfortunately. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `BYROW()` with `TEXTJOIN()`. Textjoin has option to exclude empty/blank cells.

```
=BYROW(A2:W10,LAMBDA(rw,TEXTJOIN("/",TRUE,rw)))
```

[TEXTJOIN()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en) in google sheet.